# Add another page if there is 5 or more rows

Tags: php, xml, pagination

I've created a table that is being populated by data from an XML file using SimpleXML function of PHP. What I would like to do is to add paging capability wherein if the rows becomes 5 or more then page 2 will be and so on. How to do that?

Comment: What you are looking for is called "pagination" try to search for that.  There are a ton of examples out there.

Comment: Thank you. I'll go ahead and search tutorials then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given XML:

```
<root>
<item page="1" title="title 1" />
<item page="2" title="title 2" />
<item page="3" title="title 3" />
<item page="4" title="title 4" />
<item page="5" title="title 5" />
<item page="6" title="title 6" />
<item page="7" title="title 7" />
<item page="8" title="title 8" />
<item page="9" title="title 9" />
<item page="10" title="title 10" />
<item page="11" title="title 11" />
</root>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('yourxml.xml');

$limit = 5;
$page = $_GET['page'];

foreach ( $xml->item as $item ) {
  if ( empty($page) ) {
    if ( $item->attributes()->page > 0 && $item->attributes()->page <= $page+$limit )
      echo $item->attributes()->title,'<br/>';
    } else {
    if ( $item->attributes()->page > ($page-1)*$limit && $item->attributes()->page <= (($page-1)*$limit)+$limit )    
      echo $item->attributes()->title,'<br/>';
  }
}
?>
```

Then you can access using yourpage.php?page=2 etc etc.

Comment: You can also have something like previous and next buttons that will point to yourpage.php?page=($page-1) and yourpage.php?page=($page+1) accordingly.

Comment: I find this answer from another forum and said that it's not the best way to do it. I'm just a beginner, but I'll try it now.

Comment: What exactly do I set from the gets elements name? You said 'page'. Also, why do you echo the attribute title? Is that for a link?

Comment: I suggest you set it up - run it, understand how it works, and then you may be able to adapt for your situation.
This was just an example, i dont know what you XML looks like - i dont know what you want to display!

Comment: I did run it but the page is empty. I tried cleaning the code but still does not work. I just want to ask what do you mean by GET['page']. I can't make the code work so I'm having a hard time to understand how it works.

My XML file contains a simple names of people and address. personlist is the root, persons as childs and names and address are siblings and persons are their parent element.

Comment: you need to do something like yourpage.php?page=1 or yourpage.php?page=2 to see the first 5 records, then the next 5 etc. Of course you would probably want to default this to 1 to always show the first five...

Comment: Hello. I've applied the pagination on my page. It works now. I would just like to ask on how to create page links, let's say I have three pages and there should be page 1, 2, 3.

Comment: You just need to look at what Page you are on using the $GET_ then have an href for the previous and next page. Easy - think about it for a while and you will work it out!

Comment: I know how to add hyperlinks manually, but how could the hyperlinks be added dynamically. I mean if I insert 20 records then links to pages 1, 2, 3, 4 will be added automatically as a hyperlink.

Comment: you would need a for loop or something to do this.... basic stuff again. You need to know how many records you have, divide by the page size, then do "for x=0 to page size .... do ... hyperlink next" or something

Comment: Hello. The foreach loop reads the elements of the XML file starting from 1. Making the page 1 attribute the first to show up instead of the last page number. I need to show the XML file from last page to the page 1, instead of page 1 to the last page. How could I achieve this? This is to show the most recent entry entered from the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Have a GET parameter indicating the current page. If it's not set, default to 0. Then, only show elements from `currentPage * 5` to `(currentPage * 5) + 5`. To link to your pages, link to the same document but with the GET parameter set, ie: `results.php?page=2`.